# How to use Entry.objects.filter() in two tables in Django?

Tags: database, django

I have two tables in Django: First one is `file` which has the file information and second one is `share` which has the shared information:
`files_id` is foreign key to `Share` table:
Now, I want to retrieve file information(from File table) which has files_id in shared table. How can I do that?

```
#models.py
class File(models.Model):
    users = models.ForeignKey(User)
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_date = models.TextField()
    end_date = models.TextField()
    duration = models.TextField()
    size = models.TextField()
    flag = models.TextField()
    #delete_date = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

class Share(models.Model):
    users = models.ForeignKey(User)
    files = models.ForeignKey(File)
    shared_user_id = models.IntegerField()
    shared_date = models.TextField()
```

I want to get the file_information with users_id is log_id and get the shared_date too. I get log_id as: `log_id = request.user.id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes to your models to remove confusion of `plural names` for `user` and `file`. I think you named them that because you already have some database.

```
#models.py
class File(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, db_column="users_id")
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_date = models.TextField()
    end_date = models.TextField()
    duration = models.TextField()
    size = models.TextField()
    flag = models.TextField()
    #delete_date = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

class Share(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,db_column="users_id")
    file = models.ForeignKey(File, db_column="files_id")
    shared_user_id = models.IntegerField()
    shared_date = models.TextField()
```

So, from above two models, it appears that `File` object is created by one `User` which can be shared bu other users. Since you have `files_id` somehow, following query should work

```
file = File.objects.get(id=files_id)
# Assuming one file is shared only ones by an user
# otherwise you should use filter instead of get
shared_file = Share.objects.get(file=file, user=request.user)
```

Why are you using `TextField` for storing `DateTime`? You should use `DateTimeField`.

Comment: I am doing this with my models:
    file = Share.objects.filter(users_id=log_id)
    shared_file = File.objects.filter(users_id=file)
I get this error: (1242, 'Subquery returns more than 1 row')

Comment: I have mentioned in comment above Share.objects.get() query that you should use Share.objects.filter(file=file, user=request.user) if an user can share a file multiple times

Comment: First I want to query in Share table to find out the users_id belong to request.user then if there is I want to query in File to get file attributes.

Comment: You have files_id with you before querying share objects for an user, right? then you can get File object first. After that you can use this file object to filer all shares for a file by current user. If you want to see all shares by an user (instead of just for a single file) you can use Share.objects.filter(user=request.user).

Comment: I am using this:
file = File.objects.filter(users_id=log_id)
 shared_file = Share.objects.get(files_id=file, users_id=log_id)
log_id is request.user.id         -----> I am getting this error: (1242, 'Subquery returns more than 1 row')

Comment: File.objects.filter(users_id=log_id) returns more than one object.

Comment: If one user can have only one file object associated with it then you can set unique=True in ForeignKey. Otherwise get all files for currently logged in user by , files = File.objects.filter(user=request.user). Now you can iterate over files to get all shares. shares = [Share.objects.get(file=f, user=request.user for f in files].

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you didn't post your models.

Presumably you want something like:

```
File.objects.exclude(share=None)
```

Comment: Then my answer stands. Note though that your ForeignKey names are quite confusing: a File only has one User, and a Share only has one User and one File. It would be better to name those fields in the singular.

Comment: Yes that works but how can I get attribute from the Share table at the same time. I decided to add shared_date attribute in Share table. How can I get the shared_date?